# Query a specific list template with a web application scope

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know that is is possible to query a specific site collection using the SPSiteDataQuery but I would like to perform the same operation within a whole web application. In fact, I would like to query a specific list template in a whole web application.

I could loop over the site collections of the web application but it is really too much time consuming.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try doing it via a [search solution](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/developing-sharepoint-2010-search.html) instead?
This depends on whether you have a content type or other property to search on, but it will scope to web applications much better.